# logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[0,2] labels_size=[32,2]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

I'm implementing a CNN model to detect Moire pattern on images by using Haar Wavelet decomposition. To generate the image data for training, I implemented a customize generation in the following code:

```
class WaveletImageGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, image_data, batch_size=32):
        self.image_paths = [data[0] for data in image_data]
        self.image_labels = [data[1] for data in image_data]
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths) // self.batch_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        i = idx * self.batch_size
        paths = self.image_paths[i:i + self.batch_size]
        X_LL, X_LH, X_HL, X_HH = [], [], [], []
        y = np.array(self.image_labels[i:i + self.batch_size])

        for j, path in enumerate(paths):
            assert len(os.listdir(path)) == 4
            LL_path, LH_path, HL_path, HH_path = [os.path.join(path, d) for d in os.listdir(path)]
            x_LL = read_and_convert_image(LL_path, 0, 1)
            x_LH = read_and_convert_image(LH_path, -1, 1)
            x_HL = read_and_convert_image(HL_path, -1, 1)
            x_HH = read_and_convert_image(HH_path, -1, 1)

            X_LL.append(x_LL)
            X_LH.append(x_LH)
            X_HL.append(x_HL)
            X_HH.append(x_HH)

        return [np.array(X_LL), np.array(X_LH), np.array(X_HL), np.array(X_HH)], to_categorical(y, 2)
```

Here, the number of classes is 2 (image with Moire pattern and images without Moire pattern). The model I used is a CNN with 4 inputs that is taken from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/Moire-Pattern-Detection). Following is the model code:

```
def create_model(img_height=250, img_width=250, img_channels=1, n_classes=2):
    inp_LL = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, img_channels))
    inp_LH = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, img_channels))
    inp_HL = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, img_channels))
    inp_HH = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, img_channels))

    conv_LL = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(7, 7), padding='same', activation='relu')(inp_LL)
    conv_LH = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(7, 7), padding='same', activation='relu')(inp_LH)
    conv_HL = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(7, 7), padding='same', activation='relu')(inp_HL)
    conv_HH = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(7, 7), padding='same', activation='relu')(inp_HH)
    pool_LL = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_LL)
    pool_LH = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_LH)
    pool_HL = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_HL)
    pool_HH = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_HH)

    avg_LH_HL_HH = Maximum()([pool_LH, pool_HL, pool_HH])
    inp_merged = Multiply()([pool_LL, avg_LH_HL_HH])

    x = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(inp_merged)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
    x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    output = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=[inp_LL, inp_LH, inp_HL, inp_HH], outputs=output)

    return model
```

And this is my training pipeline:

```
train_gen, valid_gen = prepare_data_pipeline(args.pos_data_dir, args.neg_data_dir)
model = prepare_model()

if not os.path.exists('weights/'):
    os.makedirs('weights/')

mc = ModelCheckpoint('weights/best_model.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1,
                     save_best_only=True, mode='max')
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=1e-3, cooldown=0, patience=5, min_lr=5e-6)
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, patience=30)

model.fit(train_gen, validation_data=valid_gen, epochs=100, callbacks=[mc, reduce_lr, es])
```

However, when I run training, I encounter this error:

> logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[0,2]
> labels_size=[32,2]

The number of classes I'm very certain is 2 (since the image_data argument passed to the constructor of Generator is a list where each element is a tuple (path_to_image, label), and I've made sure that the label is either 0 or 1), and from what I'm seeing here, the output of the model has shape (None, 2). Therefore I don't really understand why am I getting the error. Any help would be really appreciated.

UPDATE: This is the function that I used to prepare the data pipeline for training the model:

```
def prepare_data_pipeline(pos_path, neg_path):
    image_data = []
    for subdir in os.listdir(pos_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(pos_path, subdir)):
            continue
        image_data.append((os.path.join(pos_path, subdir), 1))
    for subdir in os.listdir(neg_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(neg_path, subdir)):
            continue
        image_data.append((os.path.join(neg_path, subdir), 0))

    train_data, valid_data = split_train_valid(image_data)
    train_gen = WaveletImageGenerator(image_data=train_data, batch_size=32)
    valid_gen = WaveletImageGenerator(image_data=valid_data, batch_size=32)

    return train_gen, valid_gen
```

so the batch size is definitely 32.

Comment: `logits_size=[0,2]` means that the array has 0x2=0 elements.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't see your point.

Comment: could you please try to print the batch size? As it seems, the model isn't really getting any input.

Comment: @LabibaKanij: I've updated my question. The batch size is definitely 32.

Comment: can you print `logits_size.shape`, and `batch_size.shape`. it seems `logits_size` is not camparitive with batch_size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, call `model.compile()` if you really miss it.

Second, check x.shape. I made mock data generator, and it works fine.

```
class WaveletImageGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
  def __init__(self, batch_size=32):
    self.batch_size = batch_size

  def __len__(self):
    return 4

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    x = np.random.rand(32, 250, 250, 1)
    y = np.zeros((32,1))
    return [x, x, x, x], tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, 2)

train_gen = WaveletImageGenerator()
val_gen = WaveletImageGenerator()
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', 
    loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), 
    metrics='accuracy')
model.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=100)
```